# Problem while interfacing LCD screen with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I tried to interface an LCD screen with my Arduino but I have a problem - Nothing is being displayed on my LCD screen:

[image: LCD Screen]

Here is the code:

```
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);  // sets the interfacing pins

void setup()
{
 lcd.begin(16, 2);  // initializes the 16x2 LCD
}

void loop()
{
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);           //sets the cursor at row 0 column 0
  lcd.print("16x2 LCD MODULE"); // prints 16x2 LCD MODULE
  lcd.setCursor(2,1);           //sets the cursor at row 1 column 2
  lcd.print("HELLO WORLD");     // prints HELLO WORLD
}
```

Comment: Probably your background is not set correctly (there is a way to change the contrast).

Comment: Contrast looks good in the photo -- one row of all-on blocks indicates an uninitialized display.

Comment: Your photo doesn't clearly show where the wires are going. Can you create a schematic showing the wiring setup, or at least a better photo that clearly shows where each wire from the LCD goes to the Arduino?

Comment: @josecanuc the uninitialized screens can be seen even if the contrast is set wrong;

Answer (score 1):

In the `setup()` you have to state what pin the Vo (display contrast pin) on the LCD is connected to. Before the

```
lcd.begin(16,2)
```

try

```
analogWrite(pin Vo is connected to, contrast you want to set the screen to);
```

An example would be:

```
analogWrite(6,80);
```